# regex get everything except last word and until find some text

Tags: php, regex, expression, preg-match, cpu-word

I have data in this format:

```
  1  DOPPEL TYP I MEERBLICK           HALBPENSION
 FRÜHBUCHER 20%
 INKL. REISELEITUNG UND TRANSFER AB/BIS
 FLUGHAFEN
 KEIN INFO-TREFFEN IM HOTEL! REISELEITUNG  IST TELEFONISCH ZU ERREICHEN UND AUF  ANFRAGE
 F367655  HERR WILKAT, CHRISTINE                           O 05.01.15
 F367655  HERR LEBEDIES, HANS-JOACHIM                      O 05.01.15
```

And I want to capture: 1 and DOPPEL TYP I MEERBLICK and all text between "FFRUHBUCHER.." and "ANFRAGE" ( So F367655 is the end delimiter) as different matches.
However I have this regex that captures: 1 and HALBPENSION:

```
$re = "/\\s(\\d{1})(\\w+\\W{1,2})*/"; 
$str = " 1  DOPPEL TYP I MEERBLICK           HALBPENSION\n FRÜHBUCHER 20%\n INKL. REISELEITUNG UND TRANSFER AB/BIS\n FLUGHAFEN\n KEIN INFO-TREFFEN IM HOTEL! REISELEITUNG  IST TELEFONISCH ZU ERREICHEN UND AUF  ANFRAGE\n F367655  HERR WILKAT, CHRISTINE                           O 05.01.15\n F367655  HERR LEBEDIES, HANS-JOACHIM                      O 05.01.15"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

I am testing here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jT9tH8/1)

So instead of capturing the last word ("HALPENSION") I want to capture everything except last word. And also whats after HALBPENSION(maybe other word) and before something like F367655  ("FRÜHBUCHER 20%
 INKL. REISELEITUNG UND TRANSFER AB/BIS
 FLUGHAFEN
 KEIN INFO-TREFFEN IM HOTEL! REISELEITUNG  IST TELEFONISCH ZU ERREICHEN UND AUF  ANFRAGE").

I have tried several solutions but I am not getting it to work.

Thank you in advance, for your help!

Comment: Not sure what you need, try [`'~^\s*(\d)\s*(.+?)\s*\b\w+$~'`](https://regex101.com/r/zP1wM7/2). This will *capture* `1` and `DOPPEL TYP I MEERBLICK`.

Comment: use `(\w+\W{1,2})*`. This will capture everything except last word.

Comment: Thanks, works but if I have text after doesnot. Sorry forgot to put

Comment: Do you have an access to a structured version of your text (an html version for example)? In this case it's probably more easy to extract the parts you want. If not, you should post several examples to see if it is possible or not to empirically find a structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *capture* the first and second values with a `preg_match` using the following pattern:

```
 '~^\s*(\d+)\s*(.*\S) .*\R((?s:.*?))\R\h*F\d{6}~um'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rF0uP7/9)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0+ leading whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*\S)` - Group 2 capturing 0+ any chars but a newline as many as possible up to the last non-whitespace (including) and
- `\h` - 1 horizontal whitespace (not inside Group 2)
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `\R` - a line break
- `((?s:.*?))` - Group 3 capturing 0+ any characters as few as possible up to the first
- `\R\h*F\d{6}` - linebreak, 0+ horizontal whitespaces, `F` and 6 digits.

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/uZh04E):

```
$str = " 1  DOPPEL TYP I MEERBLICK           HALBPENSION\n FRÜHBUCHER 20%\n INKL. REISELEITUNG UND TRANSFER AB/BIS\n FLUGHAFEN\n KEIN INFO-TREFFEN IM HOTEL! REISELEITUNG  IST TELEFONISCH ZU ERREICHEN UND AUF  ANFRAGE\n F367655  HERR WILKAT, CHRISTINE                           O 05.01.15\n F367655  HERR LEBEDIES, HANS-JOACHIM                      O 05.01.15"; 
preg_match('~^\s*(\d+)\s*(.*\S) .*\R((?s:.*?))\R\h*F\d{6}~um', $str, $m);
array_shift($m);
print_r($m);
```

Comment: Thanks, works but if I have text after doesnot. Sorry forgot to put

Comment: yes thank you , and to capture whats after HALBPENSION(maybe other word) and before something like F999999 ? Thanks!!

Comment: I am sorry, your input string has no `F999999`, but to capture another "word" after `HALBPENSION`, you may add `.*(?:\s*(\w+))?` at the end of the regex: [`'~^\s*(\d+)\s*(.*\S) .*(?:\s*(\w+))?~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/rF0uP7/3)

Comment: F999999 I mean a word that starts with a F and has 6 digits.

Comment: Like [`'~^\s*(\d+)\s*(.*\S) .*(?:\R\h*+(?!F\d{6}\b).*)*\R\h*(F\d{6})~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/rF0uP7/6)? Or a bit shorter - [`'~^\s*(\d+)\s*(.*\S) (?s:.*?)\R\h*(F\d{6})~'`](https://regex101.com/r/rF0uP7/7)?

Comment: Sorry, no I want to capture what is between "HALPENSION" AND "F367655". So match 3 would be: " FRÜHBUCHER 20% INKL. REISELEITUNG UND TRANSFER AB/BIS FLUGHAFEN KEIN INFO-TREFFEN IM HOTEL! REISELEITUNG IST TELEFONISCH ZU ERREICHEN UND AUF ANFRAGE"

Comment: Use [`'~^\s*(\d+)\s*(.*\S) .*\R((?s:.*?))\R\h*F\d{6}~um'`](https://regex101.com/r/rF0uP7/9)

Comment: Great!! just one more question: And if the string doesn't have a F999999, can it match with everthing after HALPENSION, so unitl the end of the string?

Comment: Then, use [`'~^\s*(\d+)\s*(.*\S) .*\R((?s:(?:(?!\R\h*F\d{6}).)*))~um'`](https://regex101.com/r/rF0uP7/10).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123485/discussion-between-mary-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

You could go for:

```
<?php

$string = ' 1  DOPPEL TYP I MEERBLICK           HALBPENSION';
$regex = '~^\D*(\d+)\h*((?:(?!\h{2,}).)+)~';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);

?>
```

`$matches[1]` will hold the number, `$matches[2]` the `DOPPELTYP I MEERBLICK`, see [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/RIkSs6) as well as [**on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/bM1pV6/2).

Comment: Thanks, works but if I have text after doesnot. Sorry forgot to put

Answer (score 0):

```
    $str = ' 1  DOPPEL TYP I MEERBLICK           HALBPENSION';
$str = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $str);
$array=explode(' ',$str);
$count=count($array);
$text='';
for($i=0;$i<$count-1;$i++){
    if($text!='')$text.=' ';
$text.=$array[$i];  

}
echo $text;
```

`$text` give output like 1 DOPPEL TYP I MEERBLICK
please try,